# How to retain the state of input radio button after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form on which there are 20 radio buttons. I need to store the state of the radio buttons if there are errors on the page(whereby page would refresh). I managed to get it working 50%. However, if i select different radio buttons on the second refresh, it would still retain the sate of the first submit.

Here is my code:

```
var x= $("input[id^='question-']");
  $(x).click(function(){
    localStorage['radios'] = this.checked;
  });

  $(x).prop('checked', localStorage['radios'] == 'true');
```

Any help would much be appreciated!

Comment: Usually the server sets the radio state before serving-back the page.

Comment: you can use cookies to save an array of list which will contain 0's and 1's for each of the radio button at respective indexes

Comment: I rather use local storage for simplicity.. I might need just a small tweak from the code above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the unique form of getting the values after refreshing the page is send the information with POST or GET, after sending the form. It's recomendable using PHP script to process the form, and make validations.

If you have any doubt, you can see here [how to catch information of the forms](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

Comment: i am limited to use JS, and the code is running on an asp.net platform. Thanks

Comment: Ok, but i understand you need to submit the form to any script page no? and you in any way have to process all the info in the form, no? you can make the same page of the form, the action method of the form can be form.asp, and when reciving the info make all the validation. I'm a PHP developer, but this link i think can help [self refering forms](http://www.codefixer.com/tutorials/self_referencing_forms.asp)

Comment: Thanks for helping..but using localstorage seems an easier approach :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like its just overwriting the same value again and again regardless of what input it's for, and also should use the change event rather than click. Try something like (untested):

```
var $x = $("input[id^='question-']");

// Set localstorage on change event per radio button
$x.on('change', function(){
    localStorage[$(this).attr('name')] = this.checked;
});

// Check all radio buttons on page load against localStorage
$x.each(function(){
    $(this).prop('checked', localStorage[$(this).attr('name')] == 'true');
}
```

Comment: and why using the name attr? if id is available?